# How to programmatically assign user roles

Tags: 7, users

I am assigning a role to user by this code:

```
$user = user_load($user->uid);
$role = user_role_load_by_name("10-dis");
$user->roles = $user->roles + array($role->rid => $role->name);
user_save($user);
```

I need to replace this role with a new role, means I need to change user role according to some condition. How can I programmatically reassign user role?

Comment: and for drupal9 ?

Answer (score 13):

Drupal core `user.module` provides a simple function to add/remove roles to/from a user. See [`user_multiple_role_edit()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_multiple_role_edit/7).

```
$uid = 12345; // The user ID of the account you want to change.
$role_id = 4; // The numeric role ID you want to add.
$role_id_rm = 3; // The numeric role ID you want to remove.

user_multiple_role_edit(array($uid), 'add_role', $role_id);
user_multiple_role_edit(array($uid), 'remove_role', $role_id_rm);
```

Answer (score 3):

To remove a role from a user you can use this function:

```
/**
 * Remove a role from a user.
 *
 * @param $user
 *   User object or user ID.
 * @param $role_name
 *   String value of role to be removed.
 */
function custom_remove_role_from_user($user, $role_name) {

  // For convenience, we'll allow user ids as well as full user objects.
  if (is_numeric($user)) {
    $user = user_load($user);
  }

  // Only remove the role if the user already has it.
  $key = array_search($role_name, $user->roles);
  if ($key == TRUE) {

    // Get the rid from the roles table.
    $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
    $rid = array_search($role_name, $roles);
    if ($rid != FALSE) {

      // Make a copy of the roles array, without the deleted one.
      $new_roles = array();

      foreach($user->roles as $id => $name) {
        if ($id != $rid) {
          $new_roles[$id] = $name;
        }
      }

      user_save($user, array('roles' => $new_roles));
    }
  }
}
```

To add a role to a user you can use this function:

```
/**
 * Add a role to a user.
 *
 * @param $user
 *   User object or user ID.
 * @param $role_name
 *   String value of role to be added.
 *
 * @see http_://drupal.org/node/28379#comment-4277052
 * @see http_://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--user--user.module/function/user_save
 */
function custom_add_role_to_user($user, $role_name) {

  // For convenience, we'll allow user ids as well as full user objects.
  if (is_numeric($user)) {
    $user = user_load($user);
  }

  // If the user doesn't already have the role, add the role to that user.
  $key = array_search($role_name, $user->roles);
  if ($key == FALSE) {

    // Get the rid from the roles table.
    $roles = user_roles(TRUE);
    $rid = array_search($role_name, $roles);
    if ($rid != FALSE) {

      $new_role[$rid] = $role_name;
      $all_roles = $user->roles + $new_role; // Add new role to existing roles.
      user_save($user, array('roles' => $all_roles));
    }
  }
}
```

**Reference**: [Programmatically adding and removing roles to users in Drupal](http://www.jeffgeerling.com/blogs/jeff-geerling/programmatically-adding-roles)

Answer (score 2):

Take the following helper function provided with the necessary arguments to replace a user's role:

```
/**
 * Helper function to replace a user's role.
 *
 * @param int $role_to_replace
 * @param int $role_to_replace_by
 * @param int $uid
 *
 * @throws \Exception
 */
function replace_role($role_to_replace, $role_to_replace_by, $uid) {

  $role_to_replace = (int) $role_to_replace;
  $role_to_replace_by = (int) $role_to_replace_by;
  $uid = (int) $uid;

  // Load user by user ID.
  $user = user_load($uid);

  if (array_key_exists($role_to_replace, $user->roles)) {

    // Remove old role.
    unset($user->roles[$role_to_replace]);

    // Load new role by role ID.
    $role = user_role_load($role_to_replace_by);

    // Add new role.
    $user->roles = $user->roles + [$role->rid => $role->name];

    // Save.
    user_save($user);
  }
}
```

The function call will look like:

```
replace_role(7, 11, 4024);
```

So above example will replace role with role ID 7 to role with role ID 11 for user with user ID 4024.